# dimensions of objects strangely shrinking inside of browser

Tags: html, css, layout, browser

This one is baffling me. My assets are shrinking within my browser, I did hard math to ensure my grid would fit withing a 960 window, and its being constrained to something smaller. My objects show up in the box model theoretically right, but when I scale the screen it shows things don't add up. [note the box model display, and the size of the window are theoretically impossible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hySzC.png)

My grid has boxes with a width of 288px, and 25px margin on the right. there should be enough room to fit that with 960, but it bumps down way to quickly

Comment: Looks like you have borders on your grid items. If so, that adds [border width] * 2 to each box. Could that be your issue?

Comment: well it wasn't that, but somehow what you said made me go back and look at it from a different angle and I found my glitch. I still don't understand how that image thing is possible, but it seems to be working, and that's all I really care about.